# Convert implicitly decimal to double or double to decimal

Tags: c#

Double Precision is: **15-16** digits.

Decimal Precision is: **28-29** significant digits.

so we can convert decimal to double implicitly.But consider this code:

```
double x = 100.3;
decimal y = 10.2;
 x = y;
 y = x;
```

`x=y` and `y=x` both of them has compile time error.

Why we can not convert decimal to double or double to decimal implicitly?

Please read  :**double to decimal and decimal to double**

Comment: @MartinSmith please read again my question

Comment: @MartinSmith He also talks about `double` to `decimal`.

Comment: Did you read the answer there? Did it address your question?

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ Jon Skeet's answer is the answer to your question. The precision of decimals are much higher, but the range is much lower. This results in loss of data both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea between these 2 types are completely different.
See this [blog](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/18/why-not-allow-doubledecimal-implicit-conversions/) of Eric Lippert.

**Edit:**

Quote of blog:
"There cannot be an implicit conversion from double to decimal because of the range discrepancy; a huge number of doubles are larger than the largest possible decimal, and therefore an implicit conversion would either have to throw or silently lose perhaps an enormous quantity of magnitude, both of which are unacceptable. There could be an implicit conversion from decimal to double because that would only lose precision, not magnitude."

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. What else could I do in this situation? Is copying the content of the linked excellent blog better?

Comment: @AlexSiepman: You could quote the relevant part of the link if possible. That would also avoid the [Link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkrot) problem.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. OK, that is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Because although `decimal`'s precision is higher, the range of doubles is bigger.

`double`s go from `-1.79769313486232E+308` to `1.79769313486232E+308`. Meanwhile, `decimal`s go from `-79228162514264337593543950335`to`79228162514264337593543950335`. There is a **HUGE** difference. However, you don't normally want to convert from `decimal` to `double`, as when you use `decimal` you normally don't want to lose precision (as they're normally used for banking, which needs to be **exact**).